# Is there a memory leak in the Android ZXing library?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, zxing, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have written an Android app using the ZXing library and I am getting an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

First, I was sure the error was on my end, so I used the Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT) according to Patrick Dubroy [Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_embedded) and several other tutorials on how to track down memory leaks, like [Android Memory Leaks OR Different Ways to Leak](http://blog.evendanan.net/2013/02/Android-Memory-Leaks-OR-Different-Ways-to-Leak).

In MAT I found that over time hundreds of instances of `com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix` occupied most of my heap memory.

**Surprisingly, I experience the same problem in the original ZXing test program "CaptureActivity"!**

After some investigation I have a clue that the activity reference in the `DecodeHandler` class might keep the garbage collector from freeing the `BitMatrix`. But I have too little experience to verify this. Moreover I am surprised that I find this problem in the original ZXing library (version 2.1).

Can anyone reproduce this phenomenon or has experienced it before?

Comment: I have never seen evidence of a memory leak and can't think of a place where a reference would be held. Where does it show these are referenced from?

Comment: How is that related to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. You need to keep looking into the MAT heap profile to determine which part of the user code is holding references to the `DecodeHandler` and transitively to the `BitMatrix`. Try to follow the incoming references from the `BitMatric`, compute dominator trees and check out the leak suspects.

Try profiling the application to see which part of the code is responsible for the `BitMatrix` allocation, try to track it back into the application code.

The fact that the CaptureActivity example experiences the same issue may be caused by a wrong use of the library, so it does not necessarily proves that the lib is leaking memory. For example, the library could have been updated while the example was left the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem (in version 2.3 of ZXing) running on the Android emulator (Intel version). The root cause appeared to be the following:
In method `selectBestPatterns` of class `FinderPatternFinder`, a `NotFoundException` is thrown when no valid (QR) finder pattern was found. This exception is caught in method `decodeInternal` of class `MultiFormatReader`. This exception thus skips the normal return of a few method invocations. I have found that due to this "*exceptional return*" the instance of `FinderPatternFinder` is not released, and that instance in turn holds on to a reference of `BitMatrix`, that uses quite some memory.
Sounds crazy, and I don't think this is according to the Java spec, so I call it a bug in the emulator.
The workaround is to not rely on an exception to signal that the finder pattern was not found. I did it by returning a few null results while winding down the stack of method invocations. This completely solved the memory leak.

Comment: Well, if true, that is indeed a bug in the JVM implementation. The control flow is entirely fine and is unrelated to garbage collection. These elements go off the frame stack; where do you think they are held? if any of this is true, far more likely is that the emulated JVM GC can't keep up with how fast frames are processed and declares OOM just because its thread took too long.

Comment: @SeanOwen: the emulated JVM is pretty fast, since it runs Intel code in fast virtual mode. I used MAT to find what is holding the elements that are off the stack. It showed the elements but not something that holds on to them. You can see in LogCat how the used memory just keeps growing until the limit is reached.